# What depends on SLF4J dependency

Tags: spring, hibernate, slf4j

I run my project with spring mvc and hibernate, using Tomcat as the server.
When I run the project, I got an error log.
`SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"`
which I saw different solutions to remove the log. 
But I can't find any answer talking about what is requiring this dependency. It is
hibernate or spring or tomcat. And why is it required?

My pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.12</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, use the `mvn dependency:tree` command to know dependencies of dependencies.
Besides, you declare multiple spring libraries and you also declare hibernate and spring-orm without relying on Spring BOM.

It may cause conflict or incompatible versions (at compile time if you are lucky or at runtime if you are less).
By using spring boot dependencies bom, you could avoid that and also probably cope with your initial issue (missing lib).
[Look at that](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.8.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent) :

> 13.2.2 Using Spring Boot without the parent POM
>
> Not everyone likes inheriting from the spring-boot-starter-parent POM.
> You may have your own corporate standard parent that you need to use,
> or you may just prefer to explicitly declare all your Maven
> configuration.
>
> If you don’t want to use the spring-boot-starter-parent, you can still
> keep the benefit of the dependency management (but not the plugin
> management) by using a scope=import dependency:
>
> ```
> <dependencyManagement>
>      <dependencies>
>         <dependency>
>             <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
>             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
>             <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
>             <type>pom</type>
>             <scope>import</scope>
>         </dependency>
>     </dependencies>
> </dependencyManagement>
> ```